# C++ Processentry32

Tags: c++, char, wchar

please help.

`PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
if (!strcmp(entry.szExeFile, process))`

Error on entry: Argument of type WCHAR* is incompatible with parametr of type const char*

Please dont hate me, I am beginer.

Thanks for helping ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined UNICODE in code somewhere or in project settings.

So PROCESSENTRY32 is unicode version, but you use ASCII version of strcmp

The solution is to use another function

```
#include <wchar.h>
...
if (!wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, process))
```

or Windows-only ( WinApi function )

```
#include <windows.h>
...
if (!lstrcmpW(entry.szExeFile, process))
```

Note that *process* variable must be wchar_t* or LPWSTR type.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
....

    wchar_t process[] = L"browser.exe"
    ...
    if (!lstrcmpW(entry.szExeFile, process))
```

Comment: No problem, dont fear to ask. Note that L specificator before string-literal is meaning that string is encoded in unicode.